# Check if any of the value in resultant array similar to values of existing array with codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, compare

I really need help to display a month list view in which deposit received month should be green in color and no-deposit month should be in red color. 
I have stuck in comparing the array values. and I am using codeigniter.

I have a table with start-date and end-date by using this I have created an array to display all months in between these dates. Please find the code which I have used to do it below:

```
$datefrom = strtotime($showrangecalendar['chitdate_start']);
$dateto = strtotime($showrangecalendar['chitdate_end']);

$start_date = date('Y-m-d', $datefrom);
$end_date =  date('Y-m-d', $dateto);
$day = 2.628e+6; // Day in Months  
$format = 'Y-F'; // Output format (see PHP date funciton)  
$sTime = strtotime($start_date); // Start as time  
$eTime = strtotime($end_date); // End as time  
$numDays = round(($eTime - $sTime) / $day) + 1;  
$days = array();  
for ($d = 0; $d < $numDays; $d++) {  
    $days[] = date($format, ($sTime + ($d * $day)));  
}
```

This code got me the Days list and I have displayed this using foreach statement to a table.

Now I have another table (accounts) with columns such as ID, Book_number, Deposit_Amount and Deposit_Month. Here the problem starts I have fetched data from "accounts" and loaded to my view using the below code from controller

```
$data['show_account']= $this->Accounts_model->get_all_accounts($sess_data);
```

My Model (Accounts_Model) is as shown below:

```
public function get_all_accounts($id)
{
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->order_by('book_id','desc');
    $this->db->from("accounts");
    $this->db->where('bh_id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

If I run the belowcode:

```
foreach($show_account as $values){

  echo $values->deposit_month;
 }
```

Its getting me the array result of all deposit month. Suppose I have data as 2018-Sep and 2018-Oct, These 2 months column should turn green in the above mentioned $days array.

Hope I have explained my requirement clearly. Please help me with this as I am already spent long hours in this.

Thanks in Advance.

### Updated:

Now could you please check my model as follows:

```
public function get_dep_month($bh_id)
{
    $this->db->select('deposit_month');
    $this->db->from('accounts');
    $this->db->where('bh_id',$_SESSION['bh_id']);
    $this->db->order_by('deposit_month','asc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

And My Controller is as follows:

```
$sess_data = $this->session->userdata('bh_id');
    $data['depM_array'] = $this->Accounts_model->get_dep_month($sess_data);
```

Now please check my View as follows:

```
 <?php

                // option 2
                foreach($days as $day) { // using your already exist $day for-loop for display
                    if (!in_array($day, $depM_array)){
                       $calhilight = "calgreen";
                    }
                    else{
                      $calhilight = "calred";
                    }

            ?>
              <li class="<?php echo $calhilight; ?>"><?= $day ?></li>
            <?php      
                }
            ?>
```

But as my doposit_month column having only 2 values ie: 2018-Sep and 2018-Oct, Instead of getting green color for those 2 values, I am getting Green for who **li** element. Not getting where I have done wrong.

[This is the Current page view which I am getting, Actually I am expecting a calendar view with 2 green fields for 2018-Sep and 2018-Oct and all other fields in Red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21kSs.png)

### Performed Var Dumb in arrays:

[Pls check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbfyw.png)

FYI:
Below is the code from where I am getting $days array.

```
 <?php    
$datefrom = strtotime($showrangecalendar['chitdate_start']);
$dateto = strtotime($showrangecalendar['chitdate_end']);

$start_date = date('Y-m-d', $datefrom);
$end_date =  date('Y-m-d', $dateto);
$day = 2.628e+6; // Day in Months  
$format = 'Y-F'; // Output format (see PHP date funciton)  
$sTime = strtotime($start_date); // Start as time  
$eTime = strtotime($end_date); // End as time  
$numDays = round(($eTime - $sTime) / $day) + 1;  
$days = array();  
for ($d = 0; $d < $numDays; $d++) {  
    $days[] = date($format, ($sTime + ($d * $day)));  
}
```

?>

Here $start_date & $end_date is fetching from another table named chitdate.

Thanks Again.

Comment: I didn't manage to understand what you need. Can you please try to create simple example? I believe using `array_diff` or something alike may help you

Comment: Hey @dWinder, Suppose I already have an array printed with a few values, here say '$days[] = 2018-Sep, 2018-October, 2018-November, 2018-December' and this array static means, not fetched from any database. Now suppose I have a table named "Accounts" and It has a field named "deposit_month". Now I am fetching this table column "deposit_month" to my row. Obviously this will display all data which is posted to deposit_month. So If I have deposit_month[] =  2018-September, 2018-October.

Comment: Here in my case, array difference will be 2018-Nov and 2018-Dec, Right? So if I am trying to display all 4 months of $days[] using foreach, Now I want to check if any of the value from deposit_month equals to any of the value to $days, then that particular values should turn green color or something for highlight. This is basically to check whether a customer have any deposit due among the given days[]. Hope You get my question. albeit I am bad in explaining. ;)

Comment: Can you please post the `var_dump` of `$days` and `$depM_array` before the `for-loop` in your updated code?
And maybe I missing something but it looks like your `li` element is define **after** the loop - didn't you want `li` element for each day?

Comment: Please check my code update with 'var_dumb',

Comment: Now I understand - notice that `$depM_array` has inner array. do this before the for-loop: `$depM_array = array_column($depM_array, "deposit_month");`

Comment: Oh God!... It's started working after a long 3 days of experiments. I could have posted this bit earlier to save my time. Thanks a lot dude. You really Rocking..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array-diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) or simple `for-loop`.

Consider the following simple example:

```
$days = array("2018-September", "2018-October", "2018-November", "2018-December");
$deposit_month = array("2018-September", "2018-October");

// option 1:
$diff = array_diff($days, $deposit_month);
// now $diff has: "2018-November" and "2018-December"

// option 2
foreach($days as $day) { // using your already exist $day for-loop for display
    if (!in_array($day, $deposit_month))
        // color in red as not found in "deposit_month"
    else 
        // color in green
}
```

Nicer writing for that `if` can be as:

```
$color = in_array($day, $deposit_month) ? "Green" : "Red";
```